# error after taking several pictures using the android camera

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have an `activity A` where I'm building my own camera.In this activity the camera is opened and when the use presses a button a picture is taken.

This is done like this:

```
Activity A:
  //this button needs to be pressed to take the photo

  public void onClick(View arg0) {
  mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
            }

  //the method that gets called
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

        if (imageData != null) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent();


            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putByteArray("imageData", imageData);
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ViewPhoto.class);
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);

            setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
            finish();

        }
    }
};
```

The picture is sent to a second activity where the user can view it and see if it likes it or not.If he doesn't likes it he can then retake the photo

Activity B:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
                //..........
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    byte[] imageData = extras.getByteArray("imageData");
    Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
            imageData.length, options);

    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(90);
    bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.getWidth(),
            myImage.getHeight(), mat, true);

               //.......
                 }
```

In this second activity I receive the bytes of the picture and create a first `bitmap`:

```
 Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                imageData.length, options);
```

After that I need to rotate the `first bitmap` creating a second bitmap:

```
bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.getWidth(),
                myImage.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

After the user sees `bitmapResult` he can retake the photo.

```
backTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //...back to activity A
        }
    });
```

The problem is that after taking several photos, loops like:

```
 activity A->activity B->activity A->Activity B my app crashes in activity B at this line:

bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.getWidth(),
                myImage.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

And this is how my logcat looks like:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
at com.Xperiaproject.ViewPhoto.onCreate(ViewPhoto.java:71)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Force finishing activity com.Xperiaproject/.ViewPhoto
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If U R Interested I Will Give You Complete Code of Image Capture Using Camera and Used in Application.

Comment: Well u can give it to me, why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have enough memory to creat your bitmap. That's why it crashes.

To free your memory you should recycle your bitmap when unused or save it to the sd card then recycle.

```
bitmapResult.recycle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Write Following Code on Button Click Event.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

onActivityResult Method:-

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                System.out.println("Dipak Keshariya");
                drawable=null;
                bmpImage=null;
                bmpImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                System.out.println("Image Path is:- " +data.getExtras().get("data"));
                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmpImage);
                mImageviewmain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageviewmain.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        }
}
```

Declare Following Variable/Objects Globbally:-

Bitmap bmpImage;

Drawable drawable;

Comment: U can use the default camera like that.But some of the mobile devices after taking the picture it will rotate it or save it wrong.And to overcome that u must built your own camera.U are lucky that u mobile saves rhe image corect and u don't have to built u own camera.