# After taking 2 pictures in a MonoDroid app the camera app stops working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

In a MonoDroid app, the following code is used to start the native camera application:

```
    internal void TakePicture(int pictureId)
    {
        var uri = ContentResolver.Insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, new ContentValues());

        var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, uri);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_RESULT_PICTURE_TAKEN);

        pictureId = pictureId;
        pictureUri = uri;
    }
```

After the picture has been taken, it's handled here:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_RESULT_PICTURE_TAKEN)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                /* The URI is not a valid path, but something internal to Android
                 * See
                 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448796/monodroid-setting-imageview-to-image-stored-on-sdcard
                 * for more information. */

                if (OnPictureTaken != null)
                    OnPictureTaken(this, new PictureTakenEventArgs(pictureId, GetRealPathFromURI(pictureUri)));
            }
        }
    }
```

The first 2 attempts to take a picture always succeed, but the 3rd time the
Android camera application allows you to take pictures but it doesn't close and it
doesn't return the picture to the application anymore...
(The event handler above doesn't get called either).

We're testing this on Asus Transformer 101 tablets (multiple firmware versions)

PS: I found this entry, but I think it's a different problem.

> [error after taking several pictures using the android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256362/error-after-taking-several-pictures-using-the-android-camera)

Any suggestions?

**Update:**
When taking low resolution pictures, the problem does not occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem on my Transformer as well, but my problem was that it never worked.  I don't think I ever tried requesting a different image size though.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent) helped me, it was Donn Felker's answer that did the trick for me.  I had to ensure an empty file was created before starting the camera intent in order for the camera application to allow the OK button to finish the intent.

Comment: I'll have a look thnx! if it helps I'll mark it as the answer